# How to to edit the dialog window title?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an add-in on Outlook which opens a dialog window. The title of the window is: [image]

How can I change this? I know the "Local" part is coming from the provider name in the manifest.xml.

Ideally it would be just that without the URL of the dialog at the end. I found a post on here from 2017 saying that at the time it was impossible to change, is this still the case? Or has a way of changing this been implemented/found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API available for setting the dialog caption. It should be set to the add-in name when you release the add-in or publish to the store. Read more about that in the [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) article.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: We have the add-in published on the store. Even on that version the (live) URL is there

Comment: I see the caption refers to the localhost URL. Are you sure the add-in running in your Outlook comes from the app store? How is it possible at all?

Comment: Sorry - The image is showing the add-in running from a development environment on localhost. We have a different version on the app store. The URL is also present when we open the app store version.

Comment: Did you build the release version of the add-in? What value/URL do you pass to the `displayDialogAsync` method?

Comment: I did yes. The value passed into `displayDialogAsync` is the same URL that is showing in the image. For the version in the app store the URL is "https://{company}/environments/live/index.html?mode=attach"

Comment: Do you see in any other add-ins the URL in the caption? Do you use a separate domain name for dialogs?

Comment: I've installed a few add-in from the store to check but I haven't been able to find one that opens a dialog window as most use taskpanes which don't show the URL. If you know of an add-in that uses dialogs I can install that and report back if the URL is there.

The domain name for everything in the add-in is the same.

Comment: Take a look at the article that I've mentioned in my post, it shows such add-in.